# Image is showing in emulator but not in the android phone

Tags: android

Here I am trying to fetch an image from a URL. The image loads well in the emulator but not in an android device. The toast message gets displayed in the device. I tried the solutions mentioned but they didn't work well.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.employee_info_activity);

        back_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        empId_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emp_id);
        name_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emp_name);
        mobileNo_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emp_mobile_no);
        panNo_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emp_pan_no);
        passportNo_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emp_passport_no);
        emailId_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emp_email);
        address_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emp_addr);
        profilePhoto_imgvw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

        empid = SharedPreferncesUtility.getempId(context);
        password = SharedPreferncesUtility.getPassword(context);

        url = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/XXXX/downloadAction.do?empId="+empid+"&folderName=PHOTO";

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EmployeeInfoActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        new EmployeeProfilePhotoAsyncTask(context, url).execute();
    }

    final class EmployeeProfilePhotoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        private Context context;
        private ProgressDialog dlg;
        private String url;

        public EmployeeProfilePhotoAsyncTask(Context context, String url)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dlg = new ProgressDialog(EmployeeInfoActivity.this);
            dlg.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dlg.setCancelable(false);
            dlg.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dlg.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {
                URL link = new URL(url);
                profilePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(link.openConnection().getInputStream());

            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return url;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            dlg.dismiss();
            String jsonString = gJSON.generateJSON(empid, password);
            new EmployeeProfileAsync(context, jsonString).execute();
        }
    }

    final class EmployeeProfileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        private Context context;
        private ProgressDialog dlg;

        private String jsonData;

        public EmployeeProfileAsync(Context context, String jsonData)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.jsonData = jsonData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dlg = new ProgressDialog(EmployeeInfoActivity.this);
            dlg.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dlg.setCancelable(false);
            dlg.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dlg.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String result = sc.NewServiceCall(URLConstants.profileDataURL, jsonData);
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            dlg.dismiss();
            if (result != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result);
                    String statusCode = jobj.getString("statusCode");

                    if (statusCode.equalsIgnoreCase("1001"))
                    {
                        String response = jobj.getString("response");
                        ParseData obj = new ParseData();
                        EmployeeDTO ob = obj.parseEmployeeData(response);

                        if(profilePhoto != null)
                        {
                            profilePhoto_imgvw.setImageBitmap(profilePhoto);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry! Could not fetch the Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        empId_edt.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getEmpId()));
                        name_edt.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getFirstName()));
                        mobileNo_edt.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getMobileNo()));
                        panNo_edt.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getPan()));
                        passportNo_edt.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getPassport()));
                        emailId_edt.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getMailOffice()));
                        address_edt.setText(String.valueOf(ob.getAddress()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, jobj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println("message"+jobj.getString("message"));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the toast message displayed on Mobile phone?

Comment: @MrSmith The one which I am displayingToast.makeText(context, "Sorry! Could not fetch the Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Check if you defined internet permission in your manifest file.

Comment: @MrSmith Yes it is defined.                                                                               <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Do one thing for a test, Type the final url in the mobile's browser. See if the image shows up on browser.

Comment: Is the actual url you're accessing an internal address? Perhaps you can access it from your development PC (emulator) but it is not publicly accessible. Try it with your url changed to the stackoverflow logo: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png

Comment: @MrSmith Yes, the url doesn't work in mobile browser. How do I rectify this problem?

Comment: @RobMeeuwisse I tried with stackoverflow logo and it works both in emulator and mobile. Now how can I solve my problem?

Comment: @VeronikaGilbert, see my anwer below.

Comment: Is the url hosted on your local server ?

Answer (score 0):

Check you have a strong enough internet connection on your phone. Also, if I'm not mistaken, the `onCreate` method should `@Override`.

Comment: the onCreate method is overidden. I just skipped that line from the code while pasting here.

Answer (score 0):

You've listed your backend url as:

http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/XXXX/downloadAction.do?empId=etc.

Apparently, this url is only accessible from your own network (from your own development PC and therefore also the emulator that is running on your own PC), but it is not accessible outside your own network.

You will have to make the backend service publicly available and that depends on what the service is.

You will have to tell us more about where the backend service is running. Is it a service running on your own development PC, or is it provided by someone else in your company, or something else?

If it's running on your development PC then change the url to be your public ip (look that up on http://www.whatsmyip.org/) and open up the port on your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both your mobile phone and PC connected to the same WI-FI network.